# Which chapter of the manga version of Gintama corresponds to the last episode of anime?

Tags: gintama

I've watched the 367 episodes of the Gintama anime which ended last year, when according to different sources the manga continued. Since there is only the manga now to keep following the Gintama story, which chapter of the manga version of Gintama corresponds to the last episode of anime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last epsiode 367 corresponds to chapter 686 of the manga. The second half of the episode (the trial) is an original story and not part of the manga.